# How do I deploy units that use the -proposed repository?

Tags: juju

I'd like to deploy some units with proposed fixes in Ubuntu, how can I have my units deploy with these bugfixes to I can test to see if my bug is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Juju to used the [proposed repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49691/what-is-the-proposed-repository) by changing `juju-origin` to `proposed`.

What I'm doing is just setting up two local environments, so I have a dedicated proposed one for testing.

```
  local-proposed:
    type: local
    control-bucket: juju-a14dfae383222222220142d9ac23c499395c2785999
    admin-secret: 6608267bbd6b447b8c90934162227b2a294999
    default-series: precise
    juju-origin: proposed
    data-dir: /home/jorge/juju-data
```