# Which is the more tested repository: backports or proposed?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, repository

I've read in at [least](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401941/what-is-the-difference-between-security-updates-proposed-and-backports-in-etc) [three](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/fatalmistakes) [places](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=885027) that the "backports" repository is more tested (and hence stable) than the "proposed" repository. However, the official Ubuntu [webpages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) state:

> "Unsupported Updates (raring-backports)"... Packages may contain new
>   features, may introduce new interfaces, and have not been sufficiently
>   tested to be included in the 'proposed' repository.

This implies to me that packages firstly land in the "backports" repository. If they are then sufficiently tested, then they will move to the "proposed" repository. Hence, "proposed" would appear to be more tested than "backports". Is this true, am I reading the official website wrong, or is this misinformation?

Comment: Despite what it says on that page, I don't think packages in `backports` move to `proposed`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 I hadn't heard that elsewhere either, but I figured the official page had the official truth. :)

Comment: Re: the close vote. I'm not sure how it's opinion-based? Shouldn't these repos have strict definitions on what makes it in?

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question to more focus on the part that seems to imply a sequence of steps/events regarding a packet/version. "Which repo is more stable" sounds **very** opinion-based. (I am voting to leave it open)

Comment: Good point. Thanks @guntbert. I meant to use "opinion" as a proxy for "tested", implying sequence, as you have interpreted.

Comment: The help page was incorrect and I have fixed it.  There is no relationship between -proposed and -backports.  The former is for testing bug fix updates, and the latter is for entirely new versions of software that you normally would have to upgrade to a new ubuntu release to get, but have been backported to the older release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was nicely explained in the answer there

- [What is the difference between security, updates, proposed and backports in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401941/what-is-the-difference-between-security-updates-proposed-and-backports-in-etc)

both repositories have a different purpose. So in terms of stability we would compare apples with pears.

Shortly:

- Packages eligible for an upgrade will have to go to **proposed** for testing. Only if they don't fail they will eventually move to the major repositories where updates will be presented to all users.
- Stable packages from later releases will sometimes be made available to a previous release in **backports**. They likely are not thoroughly tested with the older release. These packages will often not be made available in the major repositories but if they do they will have to survive testing in **proposed** first.

Comment: I did read the other answer (and linked it in my question), but I was just confused since it conflicted with the official webpage. Ok, so from proposed, packages can go to major or backports then. So then I guess the official webpage is incorrect.