# What is the meaning of the different Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins?

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

Sounds extremely basic, yet I could not actually find the meaning of the different options available to configure unattended-upgrades...
In particular, what is the difference between these two ?
`"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
 "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";`

**[Edit]:** One good source of explanations can be found here (thanks @muru):
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuUpdates
but I haven't been able to find an explanation anywhere for what the first line (without `'-[type]'`) refers to...

I've noticed that having the first line activated will automatically update MySQL for example. If not, I get MySQL packages as 'available but not updated'... I want to go for option 1, but I'd just like to understand why ! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between security, updates, proposed and backports in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401941/what-is-the-difference-between-security-updates-proposed-and-backports-in-etc)

Comment: @muru thanks for the link, does provide some interesting info (I've edited to include this) - however I'm still stumped on that first line.

Comment: Found a little more info (in French) about where this came from: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2002081 : a while back, following an upgrade I got an extra "50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old" file created. The difference between new and old versions was the first line mentioned in my post. So it seems to be a new option, for what it's worth !

Comment: Have a look at for that one https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#How_are_components_and_pockets_used_in_the_builds.2C_and_how_do_they_affect_security_updates.3F

Comment: @muru - I'll take that! "The release pocket is simply the name of the release, and the other pockets are denoted by <release name>-<pocket>." Still not 100% sure what that really means, but I've now got an explanation and I know my first line refers to the `release pocket` - Thanks !!!

Comment: look at the bullet points below that paragraph

Comment: yes, think I've got it now, i'll rest in peace :) I'll add as answer to close this thread - thanks again @muru

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line was added in unattended-upgrades package Version: 0.90ubuntu0.1:

> Modify data/50unattended-upgrades.Ubuntu such that the release pocket
>   is 
>       an allowed origin so that security updates with a new dependency will be 
>       upgraded and the new dependency will be installed.

from:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/xenial/main/updates/unattended-upgrades