# Problem using wildcard with apt

Tags: apt

When I run this command :

```
apt install libkf5*
```

I get the following error :

```
Unable to locate package libkf5*
```

I'm sure that the packages whose names start with `libkf5` exist (tab-completion says so) . So the problem is not about the absence of those packages.(Note the asterisk at the end of that error message , the wildcard's not working at all)
I use `apt` v.1.9.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can be a very dangerous way to locate a package. If you are not careful, you might install something you didn't expect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Recent versions of `apt` [changed the way patterns are specified](https://blog.jak-linux.org/2020/03/07/apt-2.0/), and `apt` no longer supports regular expressions directly or wildcards, other than `*` for which support was [restored in 2.1.0](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1141203/accepted-apt-210-source-into-unstable/) and [backported to 2.0.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/2.0.3).

You should now use

```
apt install '~nlibkf5.*'
```

with apt between 1.9.9 and 2.0.2, or the long form

```
apt install '?name(libkf5.*)'
```

available slightly earlier.

See [the `apt-patterns` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt-patterns.7) (`man apt-patterns`) for details.

Comment: as a quick workaround for Ubuntu 20.04 users, `apt-get` still support the old `*name*` syntax; also Ubuntu 20.10's apt re-added support for the `*name*` syntax, meaning it's almost certain that the next LTS will also support it ^^ (for some reason it was just unsupported in specifically 20.04)

Answer (score 8):

One can still use plain `apt-get` for such purpose.

For the OP's example it will look like

`sudo apt-get install "libkf5*"`

Comment: Thanks N0rbert. Apt-get should be backward-compatible (but not apt ) as stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/446484/1001338), so it should work.

Comment: Note that, if one is to do this, one should still quote the pattern so that the shell does not expand it. Otherwise, strange and undesired results will ensue if any file in the current directory is (in the example given here) named starting with `libkf5`. In place of `libkf5*`, any of `'libkf5*'`, `"libkf5*"`, or `libkf5\*` will prevent the shell from doing its own expansion (and the shell performs quote removal before passing the argument to `apt-get`, so `apt-get` will itself see `libkf5*`).

Answer (score 3):

Per the changelog of apt, [version 2.1.0](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/2.1.0):

```
* Reinstate * wildcards (Closes: #953531) (LP: #1872200)
```

(Link: Launchpad [#1872200](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1872200))

The asterisk (and only asterisk) has been restored for all `apt` subcommands, including `apt install`.

While 2.1.0 is too new to be shipped to Focal, it's been backported to [2.0.3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/2.0.3) which is available in the `focal-proposed` repository. You can refer to [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) for enabling the Proposed repository, and then you can install apt 2.0.3 which has this feature backported.

See for yourself:

[image]

**Note**: You may want to read [What is the "proposed" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49691/612877) before proceeding with the Proposed repository.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 20.04 introduced Apt 2.0

From the [Release Notes](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2020/03/msg00052.html):

> #### New Features
>
> - Commands accepting package names now accept aptitude-style patterns. The   syntax of patterns is mostly a subset of aptitude, see
>   `apt-patterns(7)` for   more details.
>
> #### Incompatibilities
>
> - The apt(8) command no longer accepts regular expressions or wildcards as   package arguments, use patterns (see New Features).

Answer (score 1):

I found a small trick to use `apt` with wildcard. We just need to alias `apt` with `apt-get`, but this method doesn't work because aliases are not passed to `sudo`. To pass out this problem, you can add an second alias for `sudo` in your `.bashrc` file:

```bsh
alias sudo='sudo ' # whitespace is important 
alias apt='apt-get'
```

Credits:

- [apt install "*" method in Ubuntu 20.04 does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233459/apt-install-method-in-ubuntu-20-04-does-not-work/1233466?newreg=89f99a3b08c64440b1b9738540c688a7)
- [How to pass alias through sudo](https://serverfault.com/questions/61321/how-to-pass-alias-through-sudo)