# apt install "*" method in Ubuntu 20.04 does not work

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, 20.04

I was trying to install all python packages using `sudo apt install python3*`, but it gave me this error:

```
newtron@newtron:~$ sudo apt install python3*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3*
```

Comment: I think you are fortunate it failed. Had it worked, it would have installed over 5400 packages.

Comment: thank you for suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 introduced Apt 2.0

From the [Release Notes](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2020/03/msg00052.html):

> #### New Features
>
> - Commands accepting package names now accept aptitude-style patterns. The   syntax of patterns is mostly a subset of aptitude, see
>     `apt-patterns(7)` for   more details.
>
> #### Incompatibilities
>
> - The apt(8) command no longer accepts regular expressions or wildcards as   package arguments, use patterns (see New Features).

Comment: so what is the replacement or alternative for it.

Comment: Replacement: "*mostly a subset of aptitude, see apt-patterns(7) for more details*"

Comment: @NewtronMalayalam The closer I can see is the regex pattern for package names.
For example if you have multiple kernel installed, and you want to remove in one command everything related to a particular version, you can use
`sudo apt autoremove --purge ~n.*5.6.10.*`
You can see the `.*` regular regex. I like this new approach a lot, it's way more flexibile once you get it!

Comment: `apt-get` works with `*`

Answer (score 6):

I have reported this as bug to launchpad - https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1860366 against Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

You can still use **`apt-get`** for this purpose:

```
sudo apt-get install "python3*"
```

will do what you (and really me) want. We need to change our habits here.

Comment: yeh. we need to change it.