# How to use apt remove with wildcard?

Tags: command-line, apt

The command `apt-get` allows wildcards for (auto) removing packages. However, `apt` doesn't seem to work the same way. For example...

```
sudo apt autoremove libreoffice*
```

...gives the following error...

```
E: Unable to locate package libreoffice*
```

Can `apt` be used with wildcards, like `apt-get`?

Comment: ah this one is even better: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218814/problem-using-bash-wildcard-with-apt

Comment: You can still use `apt-get` instead with `sudo apt-get autoremove libreoffice*`.