# I keep getting this error when I try running sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-current : Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have Ubuntu 18.04.

@adarsh, as suggested, I did to the purge, and followed with a variety of reinstalls (eg, sudo apt-get install nvidia-current), but keep coming back to that same issue. I may not be installing properly. I have 18.04, with "EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER GAMING 8GB Blower Fan." I am new to linux (ex-windows guy). Can you recommend a specific install sequence to follow the purge? The most recent error is "nvidia-current : Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Folks, I could use some help here.

Comment: I know it's been 2 months now but are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is something problem with nvidia drivers.

To solve this I would recommend first to remove the drivers using the command

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

then try to install the drivers from addtional drivers in software and updates. If you still get the error please let me know :)

Comment: Note for future readers: Apt wildcards like `*` work in Ubuntu 18.04 and older. They don't work in Ubuntu 20.04 and newer (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218814 for the new way)

Comment: I did to the purge, and followed with a variety of reinstalls (eg, sudo apt-get install nvidia-current), but keep coming back to that same issue.  I may not be installing properly.  I have 18.04, with "EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER GAMING 8GB Blower Fan."  I am new to linux (ex-windows guy).  Can you recommend a specific install sequence to follow the purge?    The most recent error is  nvidia-current : Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @adarsh please see above reply.  Also, i tried "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" and i get "ubuntu-drivers: command not found"