# Using wildcards with apt-get in fish

Tags: command-line, apt, fish

While attempting to remove all the Ubuntu MATE stuff that got onto my system, fish seemed to reject wildcards for apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-*
fish: No matches for wildcard “mate-*”. See `help expand`.
```

I have to switch over to bash every time I want to mass remove/install packages. Is there any way to use wildcards in fish for apt-get?

Comment: When you tap TAB button in you keyboard after typped "...remove mate, what's happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing here is ambiguous even in bash.

In bash, if the `noglob` option is not set and `mate-*` matches one or more files in the current directory, it will be expanded to a list of those files which will be passed as arguments to `apt-get remove`. Otherwise, it will be passed literally to the `apt-get` command unless:

- the `failglob` option is set, in which case the behavior will be the same as in `fish`
- the `nullglob` option is set, in which case `mate-*` will be removed altogether

In fish, the behavior appears to be equivalent to bash's `failglob`, and there does not seem to be an equivalent of bash's `set -o noglob` or `set -f`. So you will need to prevent globbing explicitly by quoting, ex.

```
sudo apt-get remove "mate-*"
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-"*"
```

(which you really should be doing in bash, for the reasons outlined above).

See also:

- [Fish for bash users: Wildcards (globs)](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html#wildcards-globs)

Also be aware that `apt` has moved away from simple wildcards altogether in favor of `aptitude`-style patterns - see [Problem using wildcard with apt](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218821/178692).