# apt install g++-10 installs clang-10 instead of g++-10

Tags: 18.04, package-management

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, when I try to install g++-10:

```
sudo apt install g++-10
```

it installs clang-10, but I don't need clang-10, I strictly need a g++-10

Comment: I *suspect* that's because there is no `g++-10` available in any of the repositories that are configured for your system (it's not in the default Ubuntu repositories), so `apt` is treating `g++-10` as a regex and matching anything with at least one `g` followed by `-10`. AFAIK if you want to install `g++-10` on 18.04 you will need to do so from a PPA (I use the [toolchain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) myself)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that the default Ubuntu 18.04 repositories don't contain `g++-10` (but do contain `clang-10`)

On 18.04, if `apt` fails to match an exact package name, it expands the name as a regular expression<sup>1</sup>. In this context, the `+` character means "one or more of the preceding character" so g++-10 matches clan**g-10** (it's just coincidental that they're both compilers).

If you want gcc-10 / g++-10 on 18.04 you can do so by adding the [toolchain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) to your repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install g++-10
```

See also

- [How do I use the latest GCC on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-on-ubuntu)

---

Notes:

1. it no longer does that - see for example [Problem using wildcard with apt](https://askubuntu.com/a/1218821/178692)

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install g++-10
```