# How do I search for a specific installed app using `apt list --installed`?

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa, search

```
apt list --installed
```

The above command will list all installed apps which is usually more than 100 but I need to see all apps that start with a specific word

Example:
I have installed more than 2 wine versions and I want to uninstall them
but when I write `apt list --installed`, even scrolling to reach the top is time consuming so I want some way to make this list smaller like the command `ls win*` in directories

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 21

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`apt list --installed | grep wine` should do what you want.

Comment: Or `apt list --installed '*wine*'`

Comment: Yeay it worked
tones of tnx
but I have installed multiple times of one package and I wanna delete them, is there any specific command for it? like '''appwiz.cpl''' in windows/run which come up with list of all installed programs so user could modify them ?

Answer (score 5):

Since `apt` version 1.8, you can use `aptitude` style patterns to narrow searches involving package names. So for example

```
apt list '?narrow(?installed,?name(wine))'
```

or (using the `~i` and `~n` shorthands for `?installed` and `?name`)

```
apt list '?narrow(~i,~nwine)'
```

See also:

- [aptitude: Search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchTermReferenceList)
- [Blog of Julian Andres Klode](https://blog.jak-linux.org/2020/03/07/apt-2.0/)

and related quetion

- [Problem using wildcard with apt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218814/problem-using-wildcard-with-apt)