About Proposed in the developing system
A proposed app should be used to be installed and tested by someone, by whom?  If no one tests them and reports the results the Proposed are useless. A mechanism similar to that for testing ISOs or to phased updates would be needed. Is there a similar mechanism, and how can I use it? Can a simple user use it, or is it reserved for developers? If I install the new kernel from proposed and I don't find any problems, how can I report it?

what app? and have you looked at github and launchpad for that app? and does this not already answer it-> https://askubuntu.com/questions/49691/what-is-the-proposed-repository

"and I don't find any problems, how can I report it?" why would they need to know that? They only want to hear what is wrong.. there is no need to fix something that works.

In the page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux I see kernel 6.10.0-15.15 as Proposed. I believe that this kernel will be promoted from proposed if a sufficient number of users try it and approve. If the number of users who have tried is not known, how is reliability decided?

Your question is very ambiguous.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  What is your goal?  What is your question?

I'll try and answer what I think is being asked.
The kernel you're referring to 6.10.0-15.15 is used in the development version of Ubuntu 24.10 (Oracular Oriole).
This version will likely change, and only the kernel team will know (maybe they don't even know at this time) which kernel version will be included in the final version of Ubuntu 24.10.
So to answer your questions:

A proposed app should be used to be installed and tested by someone, by whom?A proposed app should be used to be installed and tested by someone, by whom?

By other developers, beta testers, and users who are adventurous enough (and thus actually become beta testers).

Can a simple user use it, or is it reserved for developers?

You can use it, but please note that this is intended for testing and developing Ubuntu 24.10. It's not recommended to install this on another version of Ubuntu.

If I install the new kernel from proposed and I don't find any problems, how can I report it?

This has already been answered - you don't report if there are no problems, because this is the targeted result. You only need to report bugs.

I've gone through the stable release update a few times and have been the one that tested packages in proposed (example). How this has gone for me:

I notice an issue in a supported package
I file a bug report and, if I can figure out the problem, attach a patch
One of the maintainers applies the patch, a new package version is built, and that new package is uploaded to proposed. They also add a tag of "verification-needed"
I install the package from proposed and report that it is working successfully
The maintainer removes "verification-needed" and replaces it with "verification-done"
An automated process kicks in that removes the package from proposed and adds it to the relevant stable repository.

Basically, I believe everything in proposed has a bug ticket somewhere and someone has to acknowledge that the new version is working before it's pushed out of proposed.
